# Java Switch not working like expected

Tags: java

So as a beginner I was trying to use the switch as follows:

```
switch (c_a.getText())
    {

        case "Customer":
        {
            new LoginPage().setVisible(true);
        }

        case "Admin":
        {
            new LoginPageadmin().setVisible(true);
        }

        default:
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please try again");
        }
    }
```

Although the problem here is that it opens up the JOptionPane in default as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add `break` between your switch conditions (the default is to fall through).

Comment: You need to take a "break;"

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're missing the `break` statement

```
switch (c_a.getText()) {
    case "Customer": {
        new LoginPage().setVisible(true);
        break;
    }
    case "Admin": {
        new LoginPageadmin().setVisible(true);
        break;
    }
    default: {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please try again");
        break;
    }
}
```

source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 1):

Within a `switch` statement, you need to place `break` statements, or else additional switch blocks can be executed. Here is what it says in a [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) concerning switch statements:

> Each break statement terminates the enclosing switch statement. Control flow continues with the first statement following the switch block. The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through. All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

Without a `break;`, your code will often "fall through" the switch blocks, as is the case here.